# Apache Virtual Hosting on OS X 10.7 "Lion"

Tags: apache-2.2, lion, virtualhost

I have spent the better part of an hour and a half trying to figure out how to get virtual hosting working under Lion's native Apache server. On my laptop, running 10.6, I was able to get virtual hosting by uncommenting this line in httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and then adding the appropriate block in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, along with adding an entry in `/etc/hosts` like so:

```
127.0.0.1 foobar.local
```

This does not work with 10.7 for some reason. When going to `http://localhost/` everything works fine, but when I try to hit `foobar.local` it just keeps spinning away and never loads anything. Running `httpd -S` from the command line shows the correct vhost configuration but that doesn't seem to matter.

The approach in this [article on setting up a native MAMP stack](http://echodittolabs.org/blog/2011/08/os-x-107-lion-development-native-mamp-mysql-installer) didn't work for me either. And despite [the report by some that the problem is because of `IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON`](http://unwiredthinking.com/?p=730), for me it didn't matter where I put the `Include` directive.

Has anyone else had this problem? And perhaps more importantly, has anyone found a resolution?

Comment: Questions about how a server environment should be setup belong on ServerFault.com.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: A service *on a laptop* is a development thing, not a system administrator thing.

Comment: I would disagree, configuring IIS, Apache or any other Web Server software is an administrative task better answered on ServerVault and is definitely not a Programming Question suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: This will just get closed as off topic on serverfault due to it being a developer using a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found searching on the same topic, the ".local" TLD is reserved for Bonjour, and it won't resolve now.

Try dscl
http://tomafro.net/2009/07/dscl-the-easy-way-to-add-hosts-on-osx

Answer (score 1):

Just throw the following line somewhere in one of the config files. Doesn't seem to matter where, as long as it runs:

```
<Directory "/Users/jakelodwick/sites">
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

The trick is replacing my name with your name. If you can do that, you'll be serving Web Site pages in no time!